# Slick Carousel - Cannot Read Property 'slickAdd' in INIT call

Tags: javascript, jquery, initialization, responsive, slick.js

This is a weird one for me.  I have a Slick.js Carousel, and after it initializes, I was to check the window width, and if the width is small enough, ADD a new slide to the beginning of the carousel.

JS:

```
var posterSlide = "<div class='item mobile-poster'>PUT STUFF IN HERE</div>"

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.featured-carousel').on('init', function(event, slick){
       console.log('on init');
       if ($(window).width() < 737) {
          addPosterSlide();
       }
    });

    $('.featured-carousel').slick({
       dots: true,
       infinite: true,
       speed: 1000,
       slidesToShow: 1,
       slidesToScroll: 1,
       autoplay: true,
       autoplaySpeed: 10000,
       arrows: true,
       focusOnSelect: true
    });
});

function addPosterSlide(){
    $('.featured-carousel').slick('slickAdd', posterSlide, true);
}
```

The Slick.js Carousel loads in correctly, and the init call fires, but then I get a Uncaught TypeError Cannot read property 'slickAdd' of undefined INSIDE the function that is seeing is the slider has been initialized.